# How to navigate from splash screen to login screen in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am a newbie to react native. I'm developing a sample app where user will get splash screen on opening of the app and later he will get login screen. But I am unable to figure out the way to navigate from splash screen to login screen.
Below are the code snippets,

**Splash screen' app.js file -**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Platform, StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default class Myapp extends Component<{}>
{

  constructor(){

    super();

    this.state={

      isVisible : true,

    }

  }

  Hide_Splash_Screen=()=>{

    this.setState({ 
      isVisible : false 

    });

  }

  componentDidMount(){

    var that = this;

    setTimeout(function(){

      that.Hide_Splash_Screen();

    }, 5000);



  }

    render()
    {
        let Splash_Screen = (

            <View style={styles.SplashScreen_RootView}>

                <View style={styles.SplashScreen_ChildView}>

                    {/* Put all your components Image and Text here inside Child view which you want to show in Splash Screen. */}

                    <Image source={{uri: 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/welcome.png'}}
                    style={{width:'100%', height: '100%', resizeMode: 'contain'}} />

                </View>


                <TouchableOpacity 
                  activeOpacity = { 0.5 }
                  style={styles.TouchableOpacity_Style}
                  onPress={this.Hide_Splash_Screen} >

                    <Image source={{uri: 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/close_button.png'}}
                    style={{width:25, height: 25}} />

                </TouchableOpacity>


            </View> )

        return(

            <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>

                <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}> Hello Guys </Text>

                {
                  (this.state.isVisible === true) ? Splash_Screen : null
                }


            </View>

        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
{
    MainContainer:
    {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingTop: ( Platform.OS === 'ios' ) ? 20 : 0
    },

    SplashScreen_RootView:
    {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex:1,
        margin: 10,
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',

    },

    SplashScreen_ChildView:
    {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#00BCD4',
        flex:1,
        margin: 20,
    },

    TouchableOpacity_Style:{

        width:25, 
        height: 25, 
        top:9, 
        right:9, 
        position: 'absolute'

    }
});
```

**login.js snippet -**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, Button, Text} from 'react-native';

// Importing Stack Navigator library to add multiple activities.
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// Creating Login Activity.
class LoginActivity extends Component {

  // Setting up Login Activity title.
  static navigationOptions =
   {
      title: 'LoginActivity',
   };

constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {

      UserEmail: '',
      UserPassword: ''

    }

  }

UserLoginFunction = () =>{

 const { UserEmail }  = this.state ;
 const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;


fetch('https://reactnativecode.000webhostapp.com/User_Login.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({

    email: UserEmail,

    password: UserPassword

  })

}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        // If server response message same as Data Matched
       if(responseJson === 'Data Matched')
        {

            //Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', { Email: UserEmail });

        }
        else{

          Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });


  }

  render() {
    return (

<View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <Text style= {styles.TextComponentStyle}>User Login Form</Text>

        <TextInput

          // Adding hint in Text Input using Place holder.
          placeholder="Enter User Email"

          onChangeText={UserEmail => this.setState({UserEmail})}

          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
        />

        <TextInput

          // Adding hint in Text Input using Place holder.
          placeholder="Enter User Password"

          onChangeText={UserPassword => this.setState({UserPassword})}

          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}

          secureTextEntry={true}
        />

        <Button title="Click Here To Login" onPress={this.UserLoginFunction} color="#2196F3" />



</View>

    );
  }
}

// Creating Profile activity.
class ProfileActivity extends Component
{

  // Setting up profile activity title.
   static navigationOptions =
   {
      title: 'ProfileActivity',

   };


   render()
   {

     const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;

      return(
         <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>

            <Text style = {styles.TextComponentStyle}> { this.props.navigation.state.params.Email } </Text>

            <Button title="Click here to Logout" onPress={ () => goBack(null) } />

         </View>
      );
   }
}

export default MainProject = StackNavigator(
{
   First: { screen: LoginActivity },

   Second: { screen: ProfileActivity }

});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

MainContainer :{

justifyContent: 'center',
flex:1,
margin: 10,
},

TextInputStyleClass: {

textAlign: 'center',
marginBottom: 7,
height: 40,
borderWidth: 1,
// Set border Hex Color Code Here.
 borderColor: '#2196F3',

 // Set border Radius.
 borderRadius: 5 ,

},

 TextComponentStyle: {
   fontSize: 20,
  color: "#000",
  textAlign: 'center', 
  marginBottom: 15
 }
});
```

Now How can I use the login.js folder in main file or vice versa?

Comment: I guess the only thing you need to check is [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you the code of a sample app.It contains just three screens just figure out from the code, How you can navigate correctly from one screen to another. The `App.js` contains the `stack-navigator`.To which all
the other screens are imported.Study about stack navigator first.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VdqBtawsx_Z0c3b7CUDv_d8lfcSlDvZo
(above is a google drive link to sample app)

- it contains three screens `splashscreen,profilescreen,profiledetailscreen`
- its a newest version of `react-native` app like after `npm` start you 
  will have to start a emulator separately then click 'a' to launch the
  app inside the emulator.
- or read the bar code generated inside the terminal which appears after `npm start` from the app named **Expo** to launch it in the device.

Comment: @ Abhishek Thapliyal  Try it now this is old code, the stacknavigator has changed i mean it has syntax updations in new react version. I have a accepted answer in this link refer it for new updation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876365/how-to-add-react-navigation-module-to-reactive-app/54879045#54879045

Answer (score 1):

In order to navigate a user using your app from the Splash screen to the Login screen, you need to either use the `NavigatorIOS` component (which only works on iOS) or use a navigation library for React Native.

Popular navigation libraries include:

- [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)
- [React Native Navigation](http://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/)

An example of navigating from Splash to Login screen using my preferred `react-native-navigation`:

```
this.props.navigation.push({
   screen: 'MyApp.LoginActivity'
});
```

In order to use the above however, you will first have to install `react-native-navigation` and then register each of your screen.

The documentation for each of the above library are fairly straight forward and will most definitely help you navigate between screens.

[This guide](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) in the official docs should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EXPO Splash Screen is already included. You no need to Add any code for it.If you want to make changes to it you can do it in **app.json**

```
"splash": {
      "image": "./App/Images/My_Splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
```

For Navigation :[React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started.html)

Expo: [Expo Splash Screen](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/splash-screens.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this library?
https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox
It will create both splash and app icon for your app.