# How to navigate between screens in react native with separeate js files

Tags: class, react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

I have react native project and I saved the home screen and details screens as oneScreen.js and two screen.js inside the src directory but there class names are different. So now I want call to them from App.js file and after a button press in home screen it should directed to details screen.how to do this using createStack navigator.

Comment: Checkout my answer on the link -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510634/how-to-navigate-from-splash-screen-to-login-screen-in-react-native/49512737#49512737

Comment: the code is not downloadable.Please can you help on it

Comment: Try again direct link - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-_LJfsV7hqywrH8KYKHU0-RmMhDRf3sP

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with bellow command. I am not sure it works on your structure. You should provide more screenshoot.

```
<Button
    ...
    onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ScreenName")}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**in App.js**

```
import Homescreen from './onescreen';
import Detailscreen from './twoscreen';

class Homescreen extends component{
static navigationoptions={

    enter code here

};
render(){
return(
   <Homescreen navigation={this.props.navigation} />
);
}
}

class Detailsscreen extends component{
static navigationOptions={

    enter code here

}
render(){
return(
<Detailsscreen navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
);
}
}

export default App = createStackNavigator(
{
Home:{screen:Homescreen},
Details:{screen:Detailsscn}
}
);
```

---

//you can put additional properties inside the navigationOptions

**in buttonPress you can call**

this.props.navigation.navigate('Home'); to navigate home

this.props.navigation.navigate('Details'); to navigate Details

---

Comment: Hi I want to navigate between screens which are coded in separate js files.So how I could do it

Comment: First thing is when you creating stackNavigator it must be created in base level. That means can be accessed by every classes. In import statements you’re accessing that classes in separate js file. After that you have to setup screens in stackNavigator.

Comment: class Homescn extends component{
static navigationoptions={

    enter code here

};
render(){
return(
   <Homescreen navigation={this.props.navigation} /> // accessing class in separate js file
);
}
}

Comment: Homescn class is referring that other class located in separated js file.. in your case one onescreen.js. I created this Homescn for if you want to add some properties like status bar or something you can specify that in navigationOption section.