# How to set rootview in App.js class react native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

Need to set Login page as my rootview and used code. if i use the login page details in app.js file getting the result but tried to import login.js in app.js file its not working

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, 
  NavigatorIOS,} from 'react-native';

import LoginPage from './src/pages/Login'; 



type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        // style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'Login',
          component: LoginPage,
        }}/>
    );
  }
}
```

and in my login.js class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.red}>Login</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bigblue: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  red: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Demo', () => Login);
```

but it not showing the login page as rootview

Comment: could you show your `index.js` file the AppRegistry is normally set in the index.js file

Answer (score 1):

I have an **excepted answer in the below question**.

[How to navigate from splash screen to login screen in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510634/how-to-navigate-from-splash-screen-to-login-screen-in-react-native/49512737#49512737)

There is a **google drive link** on it from where you can **download a sample project**, its a simple app figure it out from the sample app how you should set up the `App.js`.

I suggest You should use `StackNavigator` for navigation **its the** **best method to follow** in my app `App.js` is configured using `StackNavigator`.