# react navigation splash screen to login screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, splash-screen

I have created a splash screen and a login screen. I would like that after 2 second my screen goes splash to log in but it's showing: `undefined is not an object(evaluating
'_this.props.navigation.push ')`

In this project I am using react-navigation

```
componentWillMount(){
setTimeout(
    () => {
        this.props.navigation.push({
            screen:'smartbill.login',
            title:'LOGIN SCREEN'
        });
    }
, 1000);
```

}

Comment: Please format the code properly, its hard to read.

Comment: Are you using any lib for creating splash screen ??

Comment: no i am not using any lib for splash screen

Comment: is the splash screen receiving the navigation props from the react-navigation .. is it included in Root Stack ?

Comment: no that splash screen not receiving any props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Below is an example of me navigating to a home screen from splash**

```
 setTimeout(
            ()=> {
              this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
                },1000
        );
```

**For Navigation you should use StackNavigator in react-native thats the proper method**

Where did you get this `this.props.navigation.push` **thats not proper**.

**Or**

I have an **excepted answer** in the below question.

[How to navigate from splash screen to login screen in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510634/how-to-navigate-from-splash-screen-to-login-screen-in-react-native/49512737#49512737)

There is a google drive link on it from where you can download a sample project, its a simple `app` figure it out from the sample app how you should set up the `App.js`.

**I suggest You should use** `StackNavigator` for `navigation` its the best method to follow in my `app` `App.js` is configured using `StackNavigator`.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you have created a stack navigator

```
 const App = createStackNavigator({
  Splash: { screen: SplashScreen },
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
});
```

In Splash Screen

```
setTimeout(()=> {
   navigate('Login', { name: 'Jane' })
 },1000);
```