# How to add react-navigation module to reactive app?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've installed the `react-navigation` module inside the project's folder:

> ~/react-tutorial/react-native/Project1$ npm install --save react-navigation
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
>
> - react-navigation@3.3.2
>     added 22 packages from 10 contributors and audited 103279 packages in 43.188s
>     found 11 low severity vulnerabilities
>     run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

But when I try to include `StackNavigator` in the Component with `import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';`

I've got the following error in the browser when debugging remotely

> TypeError: bundle.modules is undefined

Comment: Remove npm modules and then run npm install , and try again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the new `react-native` version there is change in `react-navigation`**. **`StackNavigator` has been replaced by `createStackNavigator`**.

You have to **also install `react-native-gesture-handler` along with `react-navigation.`**(commands below)

```
 npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler // install

 react-native link react-native-gesture-handler  // link
```

**I will help with some syntax below**

```
old version below -

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

    const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator({
      Splash: { screen: Splash },
      Login: { screen: Login },
     }, {
        // Default config for all screens
        headerMode: 'none',
        initialRouteName: 'Splash',
      });

New Version below - 

import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Splash: { screen: Splash }
},
  {
    // Default config for all screens
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Splash'
  });

const PrimaryNav = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```